# The new AIIB, Japan and America

Tags: international-economics, political-economy

The **AIIB** is the Asian Infrastructure Investment Bank. It's an international financial institution proposed by China. Almost all Asian countries have joined and a lot of European countries. [Here is the link to the Wikipedia page](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asian_Infrastructure_Investment_Bank)

My question: How come Japan is not part of the AIIB ? Why are all the countries of North America against it ?

Comment: You can at least spell out what AIIB is. Don' take for granted that all acronyms are immediately and universally recognized. But also, _why_ should _any_ country be "against: or "for" the AIIB"? You should provide such kind of information-argument in your question, otherwise it is unanswerable.

Comment: The answer relates more to geopolitics than economics. Basically, Japan has a large stake in the Asian Development Bank and isn't interested in extending Chinese influence.